# If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $D: \{z\mid z \lt 1 \}$, and there are infinite points $z_n \in D$ so that $f(z_n)=0$, is $f(z)=0$ for every $z \in D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $D: \{z\mid z \lt 1 \}$, and there are infinite points $z_n \in D$ so that $f(z_n)=0$, is $f(z)=0$ for every $z \in D$?

It reminds me of the identity theorem, but no sure if that's the correct direction.

Any hint will be great. Note: It might be untrue, just need a way to refute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give another example, the function $f(z)=\sin \frac{1}{z}$ has an essential singularity at the origin, and infinitely many zeros in any interval of the form $[0,\epsilon]$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

Thus, the shifted function $f(z+1)=\sin \frac{1}{z+1}$ is a valid counter-example.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you know that the map $C : z \to \frac{z-i}{z + i}$ send the upperhalf plane $\{(x,y): y>0 \}$ in a 1-1 way onto the unit disc $D$. The function $g(z):=\sin(z-i)$ has infinite zeros in the upperhalf plane. Then $f(z) = (g \circ C^{-1})(z)$ is holomorphic non zero and has infinite zeroes in $D$.